# Kotlin 2 Errors: error: unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) AND error: smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because

Tags: java, kotlin, compiler-errors

I am trying the LeetCode 2-Sum problem and I am trying the following code:

```
var h = HashMap<Int, Int>()
var a = IntArray(2)
...few lines down...
a[1] = h.get(nums[i])
```

And I get an error that says **error: smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'h.get(nums[i])' is a complex expression**

And I try to remedy this by modifying the first line of the code to be:

```
var h = HashMap<Int, Int>()?
```

And then I get the following error: **error: unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)**

What am I doing wrong? Why is the ? not working?
Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the declaration of `nums` or `i`. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: nums is an input array nums: IntArray and i is simply an iteration variable. For the for loop: for (i in nums.indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map.get returns a nullable type (it returns null if the key is not found).

If you want to assign the result to a non-nullable left hand side (like `a[1]`), you need to do one of these things:

A) Provide a default value to use if the key is absent:

```
a[1] = h.get(nums[i]) ?: 0

// or

a[1] = h.getOrDefault(nums[i], 0)
```

B) Throw an exception if the key is not present:

```
a[1] = h.get(nums[i]) ?: throw IllegalStateException()
```

C) Tell the compiler you are *absolutely sure* the value is not null, using the `!!` operator (this is dangerous, and generally discouraged since it can lead to `NullPointerException`s):

```
a[1] = h.get(nums[i])!!
```

Alternatively, if you actually want to assign null to `a[1]`, you'll need to declare the array differently:

```
var a = arrayOfNulls<Int>(2)
```

---

As for this...

```
var h = HashMap<Int, Int>()?
```

The `?` is in the wrong place. If your intent were to declare a nullable variable that refers to a mutable map, you could write:

```
var h: MutableMap<Int, Int>? = HashMap<Int, Int>()
```

... but that probably won't help solve your problem :-)

Comment: Thank you! Solution A) worked. I gave it a default value